# Redirect to 404 if there is no query string, react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i'm a beginner in using react-router and also react itself. I have a route that links to '/items' and it depends on a query string ex. 'items?item_id=156' and displays the info of the item. I make it work just like that but i want to show 404 if the user only visited '/items' without query string.

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a [wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) match in this case. You could do something like :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter , Route ) from 'react-router-dom;
import NotFound from './NotFound'
import ItemPage from './ItemPage'

const routes = (    import NotFound from './NotFound'

               <BrowserRouter>
                  <Switch>
                     <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
                     <Route path="/items/:id/" component={ItemPage}/>
                  </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>

               )
```

**This assumes you are using react-router v4.**

Comment: Yes i am currently using react-router v4, this is also what i did but is there a way i could use query string because i can give it multiple query/param e.g 'items?item_id=1&sample=2.

Comment: You could do something like `path='/item/:id/:sample'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a redirect if the `item_id` is not parseable. For example:

```
import queryString from 'query-string'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Items() {
  const queryValues = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
  const itemId = queryValues['item_id']

  if (isNaN(itemId)) {
    return <Redirect to="/404.html" />
  }
  return ...
}
```